# want to compare the text entered in textbox with the sql column, and to pull the other values from that row, if the values matches using asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I want to compare the data entered in `textbox` with the column data in the `SQL`.if the `text` entered matches with the `text` present in the `sql column`, then i want to pull some values present in that row to the front end.

**below Code not working :**

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
      SqlDataReader reader = null;
      SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=PRATHAP-GENNY\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Testing;Integrated Security=True");
      conn.Open();
      SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select barcodetest from Testtable where @barcodetest='" + barcode.Text + "'", conn);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@barcodetest", barcode.Text);
      reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
     if (reader != null && reader.HasRows)
        {
     //email exists in db do something
            TextBox2.Visible = true;

        }
     else
       {

     TextBox3.Visible = true;
        }

  }
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Are you looking for autocomplete? http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

Comment: could you please provide some code you wrote - the question is otherwise a bit vague

Comment: looking at the code i guess he is a newbie.. who is experimenting his first error in a asp.net page. because his sql statement is wrong or if not then its really very new to me.

Answer (score 4):

Here are two different sets of code which I have written for you. Try copy pasting them. 
I believe they will work.

```
        SqlDataReader reader = null;
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=PRATHAP-GENNY\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Testing;Integrated Security=True");
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select barcodetest from Testtable where barcodetest=@barcodetest", conn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@barcodetest", barcode.Text);
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (reader != null && reader.HasRows)
        {
            //email exists in db do something
            TextBox2.Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {

            TextBox3.Visible = true;
        }
```

Below I have written another modified code as you do not get anything from your SQL Command.
Hence I bought an extra value. Which might give an error as this column will not be present in your table.

Just to give you an idea how to read those values

```
 // My MODIFIED CODE WOULD BE
        SqlDataReader reader = null;
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=PRATHAP-GENNY\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Testing;Integrated Security=True");
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select productname, barcodetest from Testtable where barcodetest=@barcodetest", conn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@barcodetest", barcode.Text);
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        { 
            textBox1.Visible= true;
            textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(reader["productname"]);

            textBox2.Visible = true;
            textBox2.Text = Convert.ToString(reader["barcodetest"]);
        }
        else
        {

            textBox1.Visible = textBox2.Visible= false;
        }
```

If there is any confusion do feel free to ask me.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing line

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select barcodetest from Testtable where @barcodetest='" + barcode.Text + "'", conn);
```

to

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select barcodetest from Testtable where barcodetest=@barcodetest"), conn);
```

Answer (score 0):

well you have everything you need - change your select statement to * or add all the columns you would need later on - so you could now enter your values into the textbox2 or textbox3 using:

```
 TextBox2.Text = String.Format("Value: {0}", reader["barcodetest"]);
```

or via index

```
TextBox2.Text = String.Format("Value: {0}", reader[0]);
```

see documentation of [sqldatareader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.aspx)