# use like or any sql query for look-up between c# value and sql record

Tags: c#, sql-server

Hi i have a label to get numbers in this format:

0123-480-1234

Its a full phone number including city code and area code .

I have a table in SQ L server for area code database .
SQ L table: area codes

```
Code    Area                
480   =  1
580   =  2
```

All i want is  when  label 1 got number in full format look up for it's area  and set it into  label 2.

update 2: finding area code for this number(0123-480-1234 ) from sql table and put it into label2

```
 label1= 0123-480-1234              label2=?????
```

update 3: label 2 have value 480  but how i can compare its value with sql area codes table?

```
string a = label2.Txt

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select area from dbo.areacodes where code=@code", cnt);
cnt.Open();
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@code", a);
SqlDataReader re = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (re.Read())

    MessageBox.Show(re["area"].ToString());

cnt.Close();
```

update 4 problem fixed :

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=db3;Integrated Security=True");
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select count (number) from t2 where number=@number", conn); // select and count number
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@number", label1.Text); //c# source
    label5.Text=(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString()); //show count
    conn.Close();
```

source : [want to compare the text entered in textbox with the sql column, and to pull the other values from that row, if the values matches using asp.net c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655378/want-to-compare-the-text-entered-in-textbox-with-the-sql-column-and-to-pull-the)

Comment: Your question is not clear. Firstly, did you make any code ? If yes, then show it here ! How are you using area code table to make label-1 ? What is label-2 ? It looks like English is not your first language. Which language do you speak ? Try to use google translate to convert your language to English.

Comment: Can you review your question?

Comment: yes 2 forms 1 class for getting number and  label1 codes are fine..and have phone numbers for me..  but i need just put it's area code into label2  just this. also i created sql database for area codes  but how i can make relation  for this?

Answer (score 3):

A lot of imagination what put in without knowing the real requirements but something like this should work in pure SQL.

```
-- Some preparation for testing ...    
IF OBJECT_ID('AreaCode', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE AreaCode

GO

CREATE TABLE AreaCode
(
    Code INT NOT NULL,
    Area INT NOT NULL
)

GO

INSERT INTO AreaCode VALUES
    (480, 3),
    (580, 2)

GO

-- This is the label you want to check.
DECLARE @LabelForLookUp CHAR(13) = '0123-480-1234'

--Use LIKE to extract its valid code if it matches the strict format.
DECLARE @Code INT = NULL
IF(@LabelForLookUp LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]')
    SET @Code = CAST(SUBSTRING(@LabelForLookUp, 6, 3) AS INT)


--This is the area that we will look up in our table.
DECLARE @Area INT = NULL

SELECT @Area = Area
FROM AreaCode
WHERE Code = @Code


-- This variable is null if area was not found, else it is the area we want.
PRINT @Area
```

**EDIT:**

If you have control over @LabelForLookUp in C#, filter it with C# as described in other answers.

Comment: tnx chris you remind me SUB STRING usage!!but icant still  select and distinct  area code from sql table and put it on label 2

Comment: It depends on what you are using for the interaction of SQL Server and your application.

Comment: tnx chris for answers  i try some code for "compare a label content with sql record on sql server table"  see update3 and im sure somthing is missing

Comment: I am not sure if you understand that your application needs to somehow communicate with the SQL Server. This is already out of the scope of this question, but you could start by reading about ADO.NET that can be used to interact with SQL Server from your application. Good link for beginners: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/361579/A-Beginners-Tutorial-for-Understanding-ADO-NET

Comment: tnx for reference chris but i'm programming for a company not a collage beginner student..  anyway problem fixed with this article:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655378/want-to-compare-the-text-entered-in-textbox-with-the-sql-column-and-to-pull-the

Answer (score 1):

To get area code from a string like nnn-nnn-nnnnnn you can use the following sql

```
DECLARE @Var VARCHAR(20) = '0123-480-1234'

SELECT PARSENAME(REPLACE(@Var, '-','.'),2)

Result:  480
```

Since it is a value set to a label you can do the following to get it from your label

```
string input = LabelControl1.Text.ToString(); 
string areaCode = input.Split(new char[] { '-', '-' })[1];
```

Now you can use this area code value to get the AreaNumber from the AreaTable.